# Convertir una lista en columnas para grabar en un fichero csv

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con una lista que tiene 162 elementos, y me gustaría insertar esta lista en un fichero csv, y que cada fila sea una columna. Llevo un rato haciendo pruebas y buscando información, pero no salgo con la solución.

Había creado esta función:

```
def guardarFichero(registro, fichero):
    n = 0
    v = pd.DataFrame()
    print(registro)
    for i in registro:
        #print()
        v.iloc[:n] = i
        print(v)
        n=n+1
```

Agradecido de la ayuda
[python](/questions/tagged/python)[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta mostrando un ejemplo representativo de la lista de entrada y la salida que deseas.

Comment: Con lo que pides, basta con `csv = ",".join(mi_lista)` y guardar el fichero. Lo demás no queda muy claro a qué te refieres.